# How to wait for IWebBrowser2::ExecWB() to finish when printing from a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, mfc, com, webbrowser-control

I'm using the [WebBrowser control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-overview) in my CDialog-based MFC window. The window allows printing, using code similar to this:

```
CComPtr<IWebBrowser2> pWebBrowser = this->GetIWebBrowser2();
if(pWebBrowser)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    COleVariant varNull;

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr = pWebBrowser->ExecWB(
        bDoPreview ? OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW : OLECMDID_PRINT, 
        OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, varNull, varNull)))
    {
        //All good
        bRes = TRUE;
    }
}

IWebBrowser2* GetIWebBrowser2()
{
    IWebBrowser2* pBrowser = NULL;
    LPUNKNOWN unknown = m_browser.GetControlUnknown();
    if(unknown)
    {
        unknown->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2,(void **)&pBrowser);

        if(unknown)
        {
            unknown->Release();
        }
    }

    return pBrowser;
}
```

It works, except that if the document is large enough, `pWebBrowser->ExecWB()` seems to return right away and all the printing is done asynchronously. So in that case if the user closes my window (that houses this WebBrowser control) printing is aborted midway.

Thus my question, how do I wait for the printing to finish before I can allow closing of the host window?

Comment: OK, whoever is interested, I found a solution. Here's an [old project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3919/Using-the-WebBrowser-control-simplified) that will show it in action. Basically you need to catch `DISPID_PRINTTEMPLATETEARDOWN` event (which is 226 decimal) in your `BEGIN_EVENTSINK_MAP`, which will be broadcast by the `WebBrowser` control when the print job is finished or canceled.

Comment: Why don't you flesh out an answer?